# Override CSS for MaterialUI's TablePagination's MenuItem

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I don't know how to override CSS for child component MenuItem of TablePagination:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TablePagination/TablePagination.js

I'm using the component as:

```
<TablePagination 
    colSpan={2}
    count={2} 
    rowsPerPage={2} 
    classes={{
        root: classes.root, caption: classes.caption 
    }} />
```

Here it seems tricky to pass the style to the MenuItem. Could you please suggest some solutions?

Seems a new version of material-ui supports this: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/11200/files. But just wondering what I should do if I cannot upgrade ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found myself one work-around. Basically its done by creating a SelectProps object:

```
selectProps = {
    MenuProps: {
        classes: {
            paper: "bar"
        }
    }
};
```

Then in the TablePagination usage I use it:

```
<TablePagination SelectProps={this.selectProps} />
```

This gives the parent element of the select a CSS class called "bar". I then just override the CSS for "bar".